# discord delete message filter

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

I made a code that states that when offline users were chatting, they were deleted and a message was sent to the console that offline chat was detected.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();

bot.on('message', message => {

  let member = message.member;
  let status = member.user.presence.status;
  let args = message.content.trim().split(' ');

  if(args[0]){
      if(status === "offline") {
        message.delete();
      }
   }

bot.on('messageDelete', (msg, status) => {

  if(status === "offline"){
    console.log('Offline user chat detected.')
  }
}
```

However, the `messageDelete` section did not work and I knew `status` was a problem.

How can I get the other handler variables and apply them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Client.messageDelete`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageDelete)  only allows 1 paramter, being the [Message](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message). Therefore, you may use the Message object to access the [`author`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=author) property which is a [User](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) object. From the User object, you can access the status by getting the [`User.presence.status`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Presence?scrollTo=status).

As a result, your messageDelete event should look like this:

```
bot.on('messageDelete', msg => {

  if(msg.author.presence.status === "offline") {
    console.log('Offline user chat detected.');
  }
}
```